# select column from gridview and pass to variable

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridviewcolumn

Below is the code from where i tried to select the column data from the  10, however code is not working as it should be

```
  string strSuppId = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text;
```

ERROR MSG:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

my markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="pProductId" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pProductId" HeaderText="pProductId" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="pProductId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pProductName" HeaderText="pProductName" 
            SortExpression="pProductName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pProductImage" HeaderText="pProductImage" 
            SortExpression="pProductImage" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pProductType" HeaderText="pProductType" 
            SortExpression="pProductType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pProductWeight" HeaderText="pProductWeight" 
            SortExpression="pProductWeight" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pProductDesign" HeaderText="pProductDesign" 
            SortExpression="pProductDesign" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PProductColor" HeaderText="PProductColor" 
            SortExpression="PProductColor" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pProductTransparency" 
            HeaderText="pProductTransparency" SortExpression="pProductTransparency" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pProductQuantity" HeaderText="pProductQuantity" 
            SortExpression="pProductQuantity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pProductUnitPrice" HeaderText="pProductUnitPrice" 
            SortExpression="pProductUnitPrice" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pSupplierId" HeaderText="pSupplierId" 
            SortExpression="pSupplierId" />
    </Columns>
```

my code file

```
protected void btnAddPdt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPdtName.Text == "" || ddlPdtType.SelectedItem.Text == "" || txtPrice.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fields cannot be empty", "Error Message");
        }
        else
        {
            OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
            mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source="
            + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Database.accdb");
            mDB.Open();
            Type csType = this.GetType();
            OleDbCommand cmd;


            string strSuppId = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text;

            string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO "
                + " Products (pProductName, pProductType, pProductWeight, pProductDesign, pProductColor, pProductTransparency, pProductQuantity, pProductUnitPrice, pSupplierId)"
                + " VALUES (@pdtName, @pdtType, @pdtWt, @pdtDesign, @pdtColor, @pdtTrans, @pdtQty, @pdtPrice, @pSuppId)";

            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlInsert, mDB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdtName", txtPdtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdtType", ddlPdtType.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdtWt", txtPdtWt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdtDesign", txtDesign.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdtColor", txtColor.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdtTrans", ddlTrans.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdtQty", txtQuantity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdtPrice", txtPrice.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pSuppId", strSuppId);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mDB.Close();
    }
```

Comment: "Not working as it should be" doesn't exactly help us understand what is going on.  What isn't working?  What happens when it doesn't work?  What SHOULD happen when it works?

Comment: Is the 11th column a `BoundField` or a `TemplateField`? (note that collections are zero based in .NET)

Comment: @MalcolmNathanielNg: Show the aspx markup of the grid. It's also important to know what _"not working"_ actually means(**never**, without excuses, use this term to describe your problem on SO!). Where do you want to get the value(f.e. in an event handler, page_load, etc.)?

Comment: Share the code block you written... then it was easy to help...

Comment: hi guys just edited it the code file is trigger by a button

Comment: actually what you are trying to achieve...? bulk insert of grid view to DB...?

Comment: No @pan what I am trying to do is to read pSupplierId in the gridview and pass it to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Try the below coding...

**Declare a variable as Global**

```
public string _Data = "";
```

**Write the Gridview SelectedIndexed event like below**

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string data = "";
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    _Data = row.Cells[10].Text;
}
```

**then change your Coding like below**

```
string strSuppId = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text;

to

string strSuppId = _Data
```

**Before the Button_Click Select the Row from GridView... then only it returns Data....**

Comment: Erm, what!?  How is that going to do anything, but get the text in the last column of the last row?

Comment: Pan i don't understand the below code ... (to get all the column value)

Comment: That code was used to retrieve all the column values in the Grid View... it search the Grid View row by row and get the Column values...

Comment: @pan i am not sure why it is giving a error for data type mismatch